# Master and child Sharepoint 2010 lists using look-up

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, lookup-column

I am process of creating a parent and child custom SharePoint lists. Going through the online forums I figured out how to create the parent and child list (relationship). However I am running into some issues that is really frustrating me to no ends.

1) I created the relevant lookup columns in the child SP list, however I run into the following scenarious
a) Not all the relevant columns are available to select from when I choose the secondary columns to display. It used to but it doesn't anymore

2) When I want to edit the Item Display Form and add a webpart the related list icons are all greyed out.

3) I have tried creating this using the InfoPath tool and adding data filters. However I get the message that I can't filter on the lookup field.

Has anyone run into SP not behaving as it should related to creating these parent child lists (relationships) and how do you go about fixing it?